# About eigenvalues and solving systems of first order linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm working on an assignment for my linear algebra class, which is about the connection between solving $x'=Ax$ and the eigenvalues of $A$. (where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix)

I've already found that there are 3 main cases:

1. Eigenvalues are real and have opposite signs; x = 0 is a saddle point.
2. Eigenvalues are real and have the same sign but are unequal; x = 0 is a node.
3. Eigenvalues are complex with nonzero real part; x = 0 is a spiral point.

in "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems, 9 ed.", but I would like to learn more about it.

I've noticed that the differential operator is linear, is there anything I can do related to the subject of my assignment? Should I consider when the size of the matrix $A$ is really big?

I need some suggestions about what can be added to my assignment and the corresponding topic/book that I should read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the particularly interesting case $n = 2$ you can plot phase portraits by just looking at determinant and trace of $A$. There are these famous trace-determinant diagrams to help you with that. You can just google this to get some nice literature.

I particularly like Andreas Knauf's mathematical physics book (chapter 5).

Also you should explain these results by examining how solutions of these equations are computed via matrix exponential and Jordan decomposition.